# Написать маску для ввода денег

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, angularjs, mask

Ребят, необходимо написать маску для ввода денежной суммы в инпут. Следующие требования:

1. Разделитель - "." Если пользователь вводит запятую, ставить "."
2. тысячи, миллионы, etc. разделять пробелом

пишу на angularJS

следующая схема работает, как мне кажется, в поиске, но как под такое форматирование написать маску?

```
/[[0-9]{0,3}\s]*?/g
```

Жажду помощи!

Comment: Помочь решиться с логикой - будет достаточно. Просто придумать, как это сделать..

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
input {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
}
label {
  border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  border-left:none;
  font-size:13px;
}
```

```html
<input oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 ').replace(/[,]/g, '.').trim();" type="text" id="i" placeholder="Сумма"><label for="i">руб</label>
```